# MATLAB pdf of filtered Rayleigh distribution

Tags: matlab, plot, histogram, normalization, probability-density

Good evening,

I am trying to program the following equation in MATLAB, which is a rayleigh distribution made up of two gaussian arrays. No matter what I do it does not look close to the normalized histogram or the generic pdf distribution for a rayleigh fade:

[image]

So, here is what I have done.

```
x1 = randn(100000, 1);
% Create a second array of Gaussian random numbers
y1 = randn(100000, 1);

% Pass both Gaussian arrays through low pass filter and save to variable
x1_LPF = filter(LPF, 1, x1);
y1_LPF = filter(LPF, 1, y1);

% New Histograms of Raleigh distribution for filtered data
ray1 = abs(x1_LPF + j*y1_LPF);

figure('Name', 'Normalized Histogram of Raleigh Distribution')
[a, b] = hist(ray1, 100)
delta_x = b(3) - b(2)
% SIGMA left out in equation because it is equal to 1 in the problem
g = b .* exp((-b.^2) / 2) .* delta_x;
plot(b , g, 'b')
```

Which gives me this:

[image]

When instead it should look something like this the black line on this:

[image]

Here is the settings for my filter in fdatool in case someone wants to run it for themselves by exporting as variable LPF[image]:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the pdf of a filtered Rayleigh Distribution, you have to take the original pdf equation and substitute any instance of sigma^2 with the mean square value of the filtered rayleigh distribution. So, the equation becomes

2x/MSV * exp(-x^2 / MSV)

Something like this:

```
            x1 = randn(N, 1);
            y1 = randn(N, 1);
            x1_LPF = filter(LPF, 1, x1);
            y1_LPF = filter(LPF, 1, y1);
            ray1_f = abs(x1_LPF + 1i*y1_LPF);
            range = [0:0.01:4];               
            subplot(1, 2, 2);
            histogram(ray1_f, 'Normalization', 'pdf');
            title('Normalized Histogram of Raleigh Distribution (filtered)')
            xlabel('Random Variable')
            ylabel('Probability')

            mean_square = mean(ray1_f .^ 2);
            filter_theory = (range) * 2 / mean_square .* exp( - (range.^2) ./ mean_square);
            hold on
            plot(range, filter_theory, 'Linewidth', 1.5)
            xlim([0 .6])
            legend('Simulation', 'Theoretical')
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code can generate the desired distribution:

```
N=1000000;

%Random uniform variables 
U=rand(N,1);

%Rayleight random variable using an inverse transform sampling
sigma=1;
x1=sigma*sqrt(-2*log(1-U));

histogram(x1,'Normalization','pdf');

% Theoretical equation
x=linspace(0,6,100);
pdf=x/sigma^2.*exp((-x.^2)/(2*sigma^2));
% Plot
hold on
plot(x,pdf,'r')
legend('Stochastic','Theoretical')
```

The resulting plot is the following

[image]

Comment: This is the proper simulation and theoretical printout for an unfiltered rayleigh distribution. So, I need the filtered theoretical and the filtered rayleigh distribution. So I guess my real question is how can I properly "filter" the theoretical curve to fit my simulated data.

Comment: Can you send a sample of your data?

Comment: here is a link to my github with the example code and the low pass filter that you have to import: https://github.com/TreverWagenhals/TreverWagenhals/tree/master/School/Wireless%20Communications/Rayleigh